# How to include link in this php code?

Tags: php, html

I'm not very familiar with PHP so I'm not sure how to do this.

```
$error["sess_msg"] = "This email has already been used. Select another one or use Forgot Password tool." ;
```

How can I make link "Forgot Password" inside this php code so that users can click on it and get redirected to proper page for resetting password, since standard html  doesn't work here.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to include a link to your php code using python? :)

Comment: Standard HTML works in a String, you must remember.. it's just a string.. you can put whatever you want in it.
Secondly, don't tag your question as `Python` unless it is python, i mostly ignore PHP related questions because it's so trivial most of the time while Python is more fun..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$error["sess_msg"] = 'This email has already been used. Select another one or use <a href="#">Forgot Password tool.</a>' ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$error["sess_msg"] = 'This email has already been used. Select another one or use Forgot <a href="forgotpass.php">Password tool.</a>';
```

To clean it up for you:

```
$pw_reset_tool = '<a href="forgotpass.php">Forgot Password tool.</a>';

$error["sess_msg"] = 'This email has already been used.';
$error["sess_msg"] .= 'Select another one or use ';
$error["sess_msg"] .= $pw_reset_tool;
```

This way you can place the link part in a variable somewhere for configuration.

Comment: All these duplicates.. Quick is the element in PHP.. trivial questions..

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

```
$error["sess_msg"] = "This email has already been used. Select another one or use <a href='YOUR_URL' />Forgot Password tool</a>." ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
$error["sess_msg"] = "This email has already been used. Select another one or use <a href='http://your_path_to_forgot_password_page'>Forgot Password</a> tool." ;
```